# How To Grab Data In Any Table Row (HTML/JavaScript) Using Tree Traversal Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablerow, tree-traversal

I have a table that looks like this -->

```
<table>
    <tr style="display: none";><td class="index">index_value</td></tr>
    <tr><td>section header</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name>Steven</td>
        <td class="height">6 ft.</td>
        <td><button class="add">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table
```

and a js script that looks like this -->

```
<script>
    $(".add").on('click', function(){
        var the_name = $(this).closest("td").siblings(".name").text();
        var the_type = $(this).closest("td").siblings(".type").text();
        var the_index = $(this).parent().find("td.index").text();
    }

</script>
```

As you can probably tell, I'm trying to get the values of certain td within this table. The first two variables work just fine because they are within the same table row; however, the last variable is not capturing the data I want (inside the index class).

I'm having some trouble understanding these methods of tree traversal and how I can grab data within a table row that is not the one which contains the button that is clicked. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: As Bobby Speirs pointed out, your use of `$(this).parent()...` targets the `td` enclosing the button.  If you still want to use `parent()` then you'd need to go up two more times like `$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(...)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few syntax errors in your code that you need to clean up, but the issue you're having with getting the value in the index cell is that you're not going far enough up the DOM tree to run the .find() command.

```js
$(".add").on('click', function(){
    var the_name = $(this).closest("td").siblings(".name").text();
    var the_type = $(this).closest("td").siblings(".type").text();
    var the_index = $(this).closest("table").find("td.index").text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr style="display: none";><td class="index">index_value</td></tr>
    <tr><td>section header</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Steven</td>
        <td class="height">6 ft.</td>
        <td><button class="add">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand better now how to use these methods.